# How to retrieve the key into a Semantic-ui-react dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, jsx, es6-modules, semantic-ui-react

I have small question about react dropdown menus.

I can extract the values inside the dropdown, but I also need the key, because my page is for selling stuff. So, it is an associative table and I need the id from each table to make my query **INNERJOIN**.

This is how I fill it:

```
let options_customers = [];

serviceList[0].map((service, i) =>
                    options_customers.push({ 
                        key: service.Id, 
                        text: service.Name, 
                        value: service.Name 
                     }))
```

My dropdown:

```
  <Dropdown 
    selection options={options_customers} 
    onChange={this.handleChange} 
    value={value} key={options_customers.key} 
    name="selectCustomer" placeholder='Select Customer' 
  />
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can get the key inside your `handleChange` function?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get the key inside my handleChange, but I always got undefined. Do you know if is it possible to have it ?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `value` you get in the `data` to the `onChange` function to take out the right option and take the key from that:

```
handleChange(event, data) {
  const { value } = data;
  const { key } = data.options.find(o => o.value === value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can I have some explanations about how does it work ? I am a new at learning React and I am really curious. :)

Comment: Sure! The `Dropdown` `onChange` function will be called with an event and the data of the selected option. We can then search through the `options` given to the `Dropdown` with [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for an option with the `value` the same as the `value` that just got selected. We finally take the `key` from this option, and we are done.

Comment: So could I apply for _every components_ ? but why it is not stored in the _event_ and we need to have the second parameters data ? because, my understanding the event provides us the attributes of the element so we can retrieving from that. Also, in your example, **o.value ==== value** is it compare directly the id because I have into my dropdown 2 sames values. For instance, id ="1" hello and id="2" hello. So does it compare the id ?

Comment: @Nightlord That's the way the Semantic UI Dropdown is built. The texts can be the same, but it's probably not a good idea to have two options with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving the feedback and the update that I have done :

First:

```
<Dropdown selection options={options_customers} onChange={this.handleChange} name="selectCustomer" placeholder='Select Customer' /><br />
```

In my previous code, I had value={value} and key={options_customers.key}

Secondly, in my handleChange, I implemented your example and now it is working
Very thankful !

Upvoted his solution please to see on the top
[image: Working dropdown]