# Jquery Selector getting previous aria-selected element, not current

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm using Semantic UI React to create a select country dropdown. In order to get values that are passed as attributes to a `<div role=option />`.
In order to get the selected div I use this:

```
  handleSelectCountry = (e, props) => {
    const selected = $('div.item[aria-selected=true]');
    const flag = selected.get(0).children[0].className;
    console.log(selected);
    this.setState({ country: props.value, flag });
  };
```

When logged, it logs the previous selected div as `<div role="option" aria-selected="false">Previous selected</div>`

However, using the same selector in the Chrome console gives the correct `<div role=option aria-selected="true">Current selected</div>`.

The DropDown code is (from semantic-ui-react):

```
<Dropdown
  fluid
  required
  placeholder="Select Country"
  search
  selection
  options={Form.countryList}
  value={country}
  onChange={this.handleSelectCountry}
/>
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using jQuery. Perhaps look into using a ref instead...?

Comment: @Andy, This was my initial thought however, the options are generated by semantic ui and so I'm not sure how I would go about assigning and/or using refs.

Comment: There is a [ref addon](https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/ref/#types-ref). Would that help?

Comment: I used this answer to solve my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51227478/10773032

Answer (score 0):

The onChange handler is called with its first argument to be an instance of a React SyntheticEvent <sup>[[1]](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/)</sup>

The `currentTarget` can be retrieved from it and the icon tag contained in it queried for.

```
const onChange = (event, data) => {
  const [ icon ] = event.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName('i');
  const flag = icon.className;

  this.setState({ country: props.value, flag });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works for a click event, but not for an arrow through the drop down and enter event.
Edit: I believe this is due to currentTarget becoming document on an arrow and enter event.